# create new column with values from another column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe

```
A   B   Value   FY
1   5    a     2020
2   6    b     2020
3   7    c     2021
4   8    d     2021
```

I want to create a column 'prev_FY' which looks at the 'value' column and previous year and populates in current year row in FY column;
my desired output is:

```
A   B   Value   FY     prev_FY
1   5    a     2020    
2   6    b     2020
3   7    c     2021      a
4   8    d     2021      b
```

I tried using `pivottable` but it does not work as the values remain the same as corresponding to the FY. `SHIFT` function is not feasible as I have millions of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('FY').cumcount()
df2 = df[['FY','Value','g']].assign(FY = df['FY'].add(1))

df = df.merge(df2, on=['FY','g'], how='left', suffixes=('','_prev')).drop('g', axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B Value    FY Value_prev
0  1  5     a  2020        NaN
1  2  6     b  2020        NaN
2  3  7     c  2021          a
3  4  8     d  2021          b
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, question: are you concatenating any columns? as I am getting an error: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: @rohitD - No, there is no `concatenating`, not understand error.

Comment: @rohitD - what part of code return error?

Comment: the 2nd line i.e. df2 = df[['FY','Value','g']].assign(FY = df['FY'].add(1))

Comment: @rohit D Hmm, it means no numbers in FY column, but string. Try `df2 = df[['FY','Value','g']].assign(FY = df['FY'].astype(int).add(1)`